# Is this Spinner fragment correct? How do you trigger an action when an item is chosen?

Tags: java, android, fragment, spinner

I implemented a `Spinner` in my "Fragment_first", but I think it's incorrect. The application is running, but is there a better way to do it? How do I add a feature where, if I choose `Item 1`, it shows me a toast with text "..."?

```js
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

            final List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Item 1");
            list.add("Item 2");
            list.add("Item 3");

            Spinner s = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that 'Is there a better way to do something' isn't a great question: why is the way you did it not optimal? What requirement is there to make it 'better'? You should split these two questions up into two posts and clarify them.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path, please do read the documentation for spinner:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Here is an example of what you trying to achieve:

```
s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) 
    {
        //Access your list object via list.get(position)
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "item = " + list.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
    {
        //nothing selected
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```